# Ethics of recruitment for the foreign nationals

Tags: recruitment, ethics

I have been working as an expat in the UK wherein I had possessed a work permit; i was recruited here as a foreign national.

Prior to my employment, i.e. during the job-search period, I was with a recognition that it is very normal for the companies to recruit the citizens over me even though I am slightly better fit for the position.

Am I wrong to assume that ethically it is wrong to recruit a foreign national over a citizen, if their possible fit for a position is more or less very same?

One of the reasons I am asking this is that I will also be on the recruiter position in the coming years.

Comment: Are you asking about ethics or the law? The law does indeed distinguish between those with an existing right to work (Nationals, EU nationals etc) and those who would need to acquire that right (Through sponsorship, VISAs etc) and the assumption is that you should only import somebody if you absolutely need to. Whether that's ethically correct is a whole different conversation!

Comment: @Dan I am asking about the ethics, provided that the law is abided by already. In my case I had already possessed a working permit for example, but without citizenship.

Comment: @Swada it seems that ultimately you are asking why a company should prefer one candidate over another. IMHO This is a philosophical question and as such can't be answered here as it is opinion based.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about ethics and inherently unanswerable

Comment: Why would someone's nationality have any bearing on ethics? You may instead want to ask why people would hire citizens over foreign nationals.

Comment: In the UK whether you are a "slightly better fit" is irrelevant, if the company has the option to fill the position with a UK/EU citizen they are legally obligated to do so over a citizen from elsewhere. So the ethical quandary you're positing can't happen *"provided that the law is abided by already"*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I wrong to assume that ethically it is wrong to recruit a foreign national over a citizen

Yes. There are legal and business reasons which make a citizen preferable, but there is no ethical reason.

Having said that, there are also social reasons unrelated to the job which some companies preclude certain nationalities based on, but those sorts of biases are usually in a grey area legally and easily enforced by declining their application without giving that as the reason.